# Assigning value to instance variables inside object initialisation in c#

Tags: c#

Assigning values to instance variables of a class.

I have the following class with the following properties. It contains two static properties also.

```
public class Levels
{
    public static string LevelWeek { get; private set; }
    public static string LevelHours {get; private set; }
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string LevelType { get; set; }

}
```

I am assigning values to the properties in a method as follows :

```
        Levels level = new Levels
        {
            Start = Convert.ToInt32(Request["start"]),
            Length = Convert.ToInt32(Request["length"]),
            Name = Request[("columns[3][search][value]")],
            Address = Request[("columns[4][search][value]")],
            LevelType = Request[("columns[6][search][value]")]

   // I want to achieve this inside the object initialisation

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(LevelType) {
             LevelWeek = "Not set";
             LevelHours = "Not set";
    } 
    else {

             if (LevelType.Equals("Junior") {
                 LevelWeek = LevelType; 
             } else 
             {
                 LevelHours = "Senior";
              }     

     }
    };
```

Then, I am passing the object `level` to a method like this.

```
AssignDetails(level);
```

The reason that I am using `LevelWeek` and `LevelHours` as static is that I want to preserve the variable of each even if the condition is not met on second hit of the method.

Note that I will access the variable `LevelWeek` and `LevelHours` in the method `AssignDetails`. Could someone please help me with this ?

**EDITED**

Currently I am having this :

```
public static string levelTypeCountry { get; private set; }
public static string levelTypeWeek { get; private set; }
public static string RateCountry { get; private set; }
public static string RateWeek { get; private set; }

public ActionResult IndexPagination()
{   
    int start = Convert.ToInt32(Request["start"]);
    int length = Convert.ToInt32(Request["length"]);
    string name = Request["search[value]"];
    string address = Request[("columns[3][search][value]")];
    string levelType = Request[("columns[6][search][value]")];
    string rateType = Request[("columns[7][search][value]")];

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(levelType))
    {
        levelTypeCountry = "";
        levelTypeWeek = "";
    } 
    else
    {
        if (CheckDate(levelType))
        {
            levelTypeWeek = levelType;
        }
        else
        {
            levelTypeCountry = levelType;
        }
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rateType))
    {
        RateCountry = "";
        RateWeek = "";
    }
    else
    {
        if (CheckDate(rateType))
        {
            RateWeek = rateType;
        }
        else
        {
            RateCountry = rateType; 
        }
    }
    var items = AssignDetails(start, length, name, address, levelTypeWeek, levelTypeCountry, RateWeek, RateCountry);

    return items;
    }
```

The function `CheckDate` just checks if the `levelType` is a date. If true, it returns true otherwise false.

The `rateType` and `levelType` returns different values. Sometimes, they return a date and sometimes a string word like "FRA".

Comment: What exactly is your question? I could not understand the issue.

Comment: "I have the following class with instance variables. It contains one static variable also".  They are properties, not variables, and two of them are `static`. You need to read up on constructors.

Comment: **This is a just a pseudo code** . You can try something like this `LevelWeek= (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request[("columns[6][search][value]")])) ? "Not Set" : (Request[("columns[6][search][value]")].Equals("Junior")) ? Request[("columns[6][search][value]")] ;

LevelHours = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request[("columns[6][search][value]")])) ? "Not Set" : (!Request[("columns[6][search][value]")].Equals("Junior")) ? "Senior" : string.Empty;`

Comment: @jmcilhinney : I have edited the question.

Comment: What is your problem? Could you please show the code of AssignDetails function ?

Comment: I guess you misunderstood the meaning of the keyword `static`. Static means (simplified speaking) that a member (such as your two static properties) are existing on the class/type level, and not on the instance level, i.e., they are tied to the type itself, not a particular object instance of that type. Each of these two static properties just have exactly **one value** (the value depending on whoever/wherever was the last setting their value). They would never have several different values for different `Levels` object instances.

Comment: That said, you can access your static properties (if that is what you really want; see my last comment) by making their setter public (remove the `private` modifier from the setter) and do something like: `Levels.LevelHours = "foo";`

Comment: FYI: Read here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members (especially the section "Static members")

Comment: Like everyone said, your `LevelWeek` and `'LevelHours` should not be static, unless you have a requirement to keep those fields shared across all instances of the `Levels` object.

Comment: @Thangadurai : I have edited the question

Comment: @Everyone : I have edited the question to what the method is currently. Instead of passing all these parameters, I want to pass this with an object to simplify things.

Answer (score 0):

I guess a `setValue` and 2 `getValue` methods are all that you need:

```
public class Levels {
    private string LevelWeek {
        get;
        set;
    }
    private string LevelHours {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int Start {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int Length {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Name {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Address {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string LevelType {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public void setValue() {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(LevelType) {
            this.LevelWeek = "Not set";
            this.LevelHours = "Not set";
        } else {

            if (LevelType.Equals("Junior") {
                this.LevelWeek = LevelType;
            } else {
                this.LevelHours = "Senior";
            }

        }
    }

    public string getLevelWeek() {
        return this.LevelWeek;
    }

    public string getLevelHours() {
        return this.LevelHours;
    }
}

}

}
```

When you declare your object :

```
var level = new Levels {
    Start = Convert.ToInt32(Request["start"]),
    Length = Convert.ToInt32(Request["length"]),
    Name = Request[("columns[3][search][value]")],
    Address = Request[("columns[4][search][value]")],
    LevelType = Request[("columns[6][search][value]")]
}


// set value to LevelWeek / LevelHours
level.setValue();

// In AssignDetails function : get the value of LevelWeek and LevelHours:
var levelweek = level.getLevelWeek();
var levelhours = level.getLevelHours();
```